# Babel with .babelrc how to fix MODULE_NOT_FOUND?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, babel-cli

Babel is telling me a plugin does not exist when it does. (I can compile fine with babel-cli, but that does not support setting `pragma` options. So I am left to use disgusting .babelrc file) What am I doing wrong here ?

.babelrc

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-redom-jsx",
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
            "pragma": "el"
        }]
    ]
}
```

`npx babel frontend.js`

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-redom-jsx' from '/home/user/Documents/my_program'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:58:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePlugin (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:54:10)
    at loadPlugin (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:62:20)
    at createDescriptor (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at items.map (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPluginDescriptors (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:105:10)
    at plugins (/home/user/Documents/my_program/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:40:19) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

package.json :

```
{
  "devDependencies":
   {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-redom-jsx": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "redom": "^3.18.0",
    "terser": "^3.14.1"
   }
}
```

Comment: have you ran npm install just to be sure it is actually installed?

Comment: Just ran it again right now, same problem.

Comment: Does changing the plugin name to `babel-plugin-redom-jsx-transform` help by any chance?

Comment: Prints same error, now it can't find `babel-plugin-redom-jsx-transform`

Comment: Sorry, what about `babel-plugin-transform-redom-jsx`. I suspect there is a typo in the docs.

Comment: That was it, it's working now. Thank you very much. If you write as a answer here, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a typo in the docs, as you can check your `node_modules` folder and you should see `babel-plugin-transform-redom-jsx`. So your `.rc` should look like:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-redom-jsx",
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
      "pragma": "el"
    }]
  ]
}
```